# just show the field comment by clicking button

Tags: comments, buttons

when we open a post, we at the bottom of the page field to post a comment
I would like to hide this field.
if there are comments, usually shows them
however to leave a comment, click a button
with this, the field appears to leave a comment

Anyone have a clue how to do this?
Through either normal or ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this very easily with jQuery

simply wrap your comment form in a div and hide, add a button or a link and on his click event show the comment form so smoothing like this:

```
<a href="#" ID="Leave_a_comment">Leave a Comment</a>
<div id="comment_form_wrapper" style="display: none;">
    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Leave_a_comment').click(function() {
            $('#comment_form_wrapper').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i will test and say something about it, thanks so much

Comment: don't work for me. when I click nothing happens.I replaced the <php comments_template ();> their code in my single.php

Comment: i found the solution using this link http://forum.wmonline.com.br/topic/214317-ao-clicar-no-link-mostra-a-div-ao-clicar-em-outro-lugar-oculta-a-di/page__view__findpost__p__958149?s=f7bf4a38100593b482cf1f1963d29f94 thanks a lot

Comment: Its an example since i don't really know what your theme is, and i guess you need to include jQuery for it to work